# Convert MM:SS to Seconds

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a time such as audio duration into seconds? The format the duration is in is a digital format: `6:30` which represents 6 minutes 30 seconds.

I've tried

```
TimeSpan.Parse(duration).TotalSeconds
```

Where duration is `6:30` but it gives an overflow exception.

Should `TimeSpan.Parse` be able to parse such strings?

Edit:

To update from a question asked in the comments the format is not always `MM:SS`. If the audio file is over an hour in duration it could also be `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Did you try specifying a culture and a format, so that it knows that you're trying to parse?

Comment: @Caramiriel no I didn't, I wasn't aware of the culture or format. Please provide that as an answer.

Comment: As far as the parser knows, `6:30` could be expressing hours and minutes, or minutes and seconds. You'll need to specify the format you are using so the parser understands your input value correctly. Have you looked into specifying the format yet?

Comment: Is your duration always mm : ss?

Comment: timespan http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: @faby good question. I've updated my question with the answer. The format can change. It's either MM:SS or HH:MM:SS

Comment: @JamesJeffery I think in this case you can split the string by ":" and then sum 3600 * array[2] + 60 * array[1] + array[0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to escape the colon:

```
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.ParseExact("6:30", "h\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int seconds = (int)duration.TotalSeconds;  // 23400
```

**Edit**: But you should also be able to use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783872%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
duration = TimeSpan.Parse("6:30", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the maximum is 24 hours. If it's longer you need to use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

But even this long time is working without an overflow (as you've mentioned).

```
string longTime = "23:33:44";
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.Parse(longTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int seconds = (int)duration.TotalSeconds; // 84824
```

You can even pass multiple allowed formats to `TimeSpan.ParseExact`:

```
string[] timeformats = { @"m\:ss", @"mm\:ss", @"h\:mm\:ss" };
duration = TimeSpan.ParseExact("6:30", timeformats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Interesting. I can get the last example to work, except it's converting `6:30` to `h:mm` rather than `m:ss`. I've just learnt you can pass in multiple formats in a string array so will try that. Getting there.

Comment: Solved with `string[] timeformats = { @"m\:ss", @"mm\:ss", @"h\:mm\:ss" };` adn `duration = TimeSpan.ParseExact(duration, timeformats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalSeconds;`. Can you update this in your answer as your answer was what got me to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple string manipulation is an alternative way to do it, posted purely for reference. I'd recommend the `TimeSpan.ParseExact()` method instead.

```
string[] splitDuration = duration.Split(':');

int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(splitDuration[0]);
int seconds = minutes * 60 + Convert.ToInt32(splitDuration[1]);
```